# Google Cloud DataPrep fails with cross-region error when using EU BigQuery db

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, etl, google-cloud-dataprep

I hit some issues today developing some new flows - the first I've done reading from & loading into EU-region BigQuery databases.

To isolate the issue, I took the following steps:

1. Create a new BQ database in the EU region
2. Create a table by uploading a CSV
3. Write a flow which reads from this table and outputs into a new table in the same database, without any transforms

And still the job fails with the following message:

```
status: {
    "errorResult": {
        "message": "Cannot read and write in different locations: source: EU, destination: US",
        "reason": "invalid"
    },
    "errors": [{
        "message": "Cannot read and write in different locations: source: EU, destination: US",
        "reason": "invalid"
    }],
    "state": "DONE"
}
```

This is the test flow:

[image: Test flow]

And this is the resulting DataFlow:

[image]

Comment: in BQ UI - Details Tab - Table Info - can you check `Data Location` for both tables ?

Comment: It's EU. Only the source table exists, the destination is to be created when the flow runs successfully. The db data location is also EU.

Comment: And the destination table - is the BigQuery dataset where that is to be written to also EU?

Comment: Yes, they're both EU

Comment: Could you please file a bug via issuetracker.

Comment: Will do. Do you have a link? The DataPrep support page is literally blank! https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/resources/support

Answer (score 2):

make sure the directories setup in the profile are in the same location (EU).
The profile settings can be changed in the user profile page. See https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/User-Profile-Page_57344911

A similar issue has been reported in https://community.trifacta.com/s/question/0D51L00004pm0mASAQ/whenever-i-try-to-import-a-data-set-from-bigquery-for-example-it-gives-me-this-errorrequested-data-was-not-foundi-am-using-native-bigquery-tables-these-very-same-tables-i-have-been-able-to-import-and-wrangle-successfully-in-the-pastany-ideas

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for my EU datasources. Even though I did have the sources in BQ in UE - DataPrep default staging buckets were in US.

I recreated same structure of the bucket but using the EU location as I was not able to modify location of the already auto-created by Dataprep staging buckets.
And this link : https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/User-Profile-Page_57344911 helped to figure out where to change temp, jobrun, upload paths after.